# Is it safe to store Auth Tokens directly in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, django-rest-framework

I am currently building a seller dashboard for a local ecommerce platform and using Django for my backend and React for my frontend. I have Django Rest Framework serving my backend API to the frontend so my question is, What is the safest way of storing the token served from Django Rest Framework in Redux so that I can use it to talk to the backend. Is it a security risk by storing the token as a normal variable in the current Redux state?

Never worked with Token auth before so curious to know if there is any security risk with how I would go about building it.

Comment: You can store the token [in memory](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/token-storage#browser-in-memory-scenarios) (redux store) or [in localstorage](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/token-storage#browser-local-storage-scenarios) if you use something like redux-persist, depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe because users do not have access directly to Redux store

Comment: Users could be tricked to execute self xss